# Send data to app without launching

Tags: iphone, ios-4.2, url-scheme

I was wondering if there is a way to send data to another app i.e. a custom URL scheme, without opening the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can launch another app using a URL-scheme (and even pass data to it through that URL), but you can't send data to another app installed on the same iPhone without launching it.

What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: I am trying to make a URL scheme that will get the current URL of a page in safari and send that to my app while it is running in the background.

Comment: That would have to be supported by Safari. You can only put data **into** an application via a URL-Scheme, to get data back that application has to implement your URL-Scheme. There is no way that I am aware of to get information from MobileSafari, you'll have to look into other possibilites.